# How can I pass HTML-element as parameter to XSLT function?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XSLT-function that I use in a XSLT file to generate XHTML output:

```
<xsl:function name="local:if-not-empty">
   <xsl:param name="prefix"/>
   <xsl:param name="str"/>
   <xsl:param name="suffix"/>
   <xsl:if test="$str != ''"><xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, $str, $suffix)"/></xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

it simply checks whether a string `str` is not empty and, if so, returns the string, concatenated with a prefix and a suffix.

The function works fine as long as I only pass simple strings. But when I try to pass HTML elements as prefix or suffix, e.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="local:if-not-empty('', /some/xpath/expression, '<br/>')"/>
```

I get the following error message:

```
SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The value of attribute "select"
associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
```

The next thing I tried was to define a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="br"><br/></xsl:variable>
```

and pass it to the function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="local:if-not-empty('', /some/xpath/expression, $br)"/>
```

but here, of course, I get an empty string, as the value of the element is extracted, and not the element itself copied.

My final hopeless attempt was to define a text element in the variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="br">
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><br/></xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```

and pass this to the function, but this wasn't permitted, either.

```
XTSE0010: xsl:text must not contain child elements
```

I probably don't understand the intricate inner workings of XSLT, but in my opinion adding a `<br/>` element within a XSLT-transformation through a generic function seems legitimate...

Anyways... I'd appreciate if anyone could give me an alternative solution. I'd also like to understand why this doesn't work...

PS: I'm using Saxon-HE 9.4.0.1J, Java version 1.6.0_24

Comment: Thanks to all who answered my questions. The solution that worked best for me is the one by Dimitre Novatchev below.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="local:if-not-empty('', /some/xpath/expression, '&lt;br/&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: thank you, that works... even though it's a bit ugly and wordy... maybe I will use a dedicated function for `<br/>`, though

Comment: Doesn't this solution adds `<br/>` as a string instead than as an element? I.e. you get `&lt;br/&gt;` in the output?

Comment: @PeterNeuhaus: It works because of the `disable-output-escaping` directive - but if your strings contain `>` or `<` you'll end up with invalid XML output

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of `concat`, use: `<xsl:copy-of>` and pass as parameters *items* not strings:**

```
   <xsl:copy-of select="$pPrefix"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$pStr"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$pSuffix"/>
```

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:local="my:local" exclude-result-prefixes="local">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vBr"><br/></xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="local:if-not-empty('a', 'b', $vBr/*)"/>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="local:if-not-empty">
  <xsl:param name="pPrefix"/>
  <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
  <xsl:param name="pSuffix"/>

  <xsl:if test="$pStr != ''">
   <xsl:copy-of select="$pPrefix"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$pStr"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$pSuffix"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
a b<br/>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine. I wasn't familiar with `xsl:sequence`.

When called with an XPath expression as argument, as in my initial example, it might be necessary to select the text node of the chosen element:

`<xsl:value-of select="local:if-not-empty('', /some/xpath/expression/text(), $br)"/>`

Comment: @PeterNeuhaus: You cannot pass a text representation of an element as a parameter. This solution creates a temporary tree whose child *node* is passed as the third argument of the function. You need to understand that `"<br>"` is just a string -- not a node -- but you want not to generate a string -- you want to generate a node.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<br/>` is not a string - it is an XML element, so it cannot be manipulated using string functions. You need a separate function like this:

```
<xsl:function name="local:br-if-not-empty"> 
   <xsl:param name="prefix"/> 
   <xsl:param name="str"/> 
   <xsl:if test="$str != ''">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, $str)"/>
       <br/>
    </xsl:if> 
</xsl:function>
```

or a 'trick' like this where you handle `<br/>` as a separate case:

```
<xsl:function name="local:if-not-empty"> 
   <xsl:param name="prefix"/> 
   <xsl:param name="str"/> 
   <xsl:param name="suffix"/> 
   <xsl:if test="$str != ''">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, $str)"/>
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$suffix = '&lt;br/&gt;'>
             <br/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$suffix"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if> 
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: seperate functions or cases work, but I would have to add a new function or when-block for each possible argument. That would lead to a lot of duplicate code, which would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: @PeterNeuhaus: Dimitre solution above is the way to go then